# Error C2676 on custom templated operator<<(T x)

Tags: c++, templates, std

I have `logger` class which encapsulate 2 `std::ofstream`:

```
class logger
{           
  private:
    std::ofstream one;
    std::ofstream two;

  public:
    logger();
    ~logger();

    template<typename T> logger & operator<<(T);
};

logger::logger()
{
  // open streams
}

logger::logger()
{
  // close streams
}

template<typename T> logger & logger::operator<<(T log)
{
    this->one<<log;
    this->two<<log;
    return * this;
}
```

I use it:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  debug::log << "Some strgins"; // works perfect.
  debug::log << std::endl; //  error C2676: binary '<<' : 'logger' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
  return 0;
}
```

What happend here? Why `T` can't become `std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)`?

Comment: It's template `T` should become whatever type.

Comment: Oops I misread the parameter name as the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::endl` is a *function template*. It's an IO *manipulator.*.

There is an `std::endl<char>`, `std::endl<wchar_t>` and an infinite number of other `std::endl`s, one for each possible character type. The compiler has no idea which one of those you could possibly mean.

It works with `std::basic_ostream` because `std::basic_ostream` overloads `operator<<` to accept IO manupulators suitable for *its* character type. Remember `std::basic_ostream` is a template too, and `std::ostream` is just a typedef for `basic_ostream<char>`.

You may want to add one for your class too, just for `char`.

```
logger & logger::operator<<(std::ostream& (manip)(std::ostream&)) { ... }
```

The compiler will know which `endl` you mean: the one that takes a `char` stream.

Comment: You are right, I knew that I missed something, solved all my confusion.
std::endl is indeed templated function.